# react-apexcharts - TypeError - t.value undefined (reading indexOf) while integrating typescript pages into create-react-app javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, create-react-app, indexof, react-apexcharts

I am in the process of integrating pages from a typescript template based create-react-app application to a javascript template based create-react-app application.
First I followed all the steps given in this document to make typescript compatible in the existing javascript react app
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Conversion-Guide#typescript-react-conversion-guide

Now after adding the new pages into the converted app, I am getting the following error while trying to render ReactApexChart component. This error is not evident when I try this in a pure typescript application. This error is evident only in the application in which I am trying to integrate the new pages.

```
apexcharts.common.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:6:1)
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:6:1)
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:6:1)
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:6:1)
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:14:1)
    at t.create (apexcharts.common.js:6:1)
    at apexcharts.common.js:14:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:14:1)
    at r.value (react-apexcharts.min.js:1:1)
value @ apexcharts.common.js:6
value @ apexcharts.common.js:6
value @ apexcharts.common.js:6
value @ apexcharts.common.js:6
value @ apexcharts.common.js:14
(anonymous) @ apexcharts.common.js:6
(anonymous) @ apexcharts.common.js:14
value @ apexcharts.common.js:14
value @ react-apexcharts.min.js:1
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23305
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25981
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
apexcharts.common.js:6
```

this is my Custom Chart component

```
const ChartCustom: FC<IChartProps> = ({ series, options, type, width, height, className, ...props }) => {
    return (
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
        <div className={classNames('apex-chart', className)} {...props}>
            <ReactApexChart
                options={{
                    colors: [
                        process.env.REACT_APP_PRIMARY_COLOR,
                        process.env.REACT_APP_SECONDARY_COLOR,
                        process.env.REACT_APP_SUCCESS_COLOR,
                        process.env.REACT_APP_INFO_COLOR,
                        process.env.REACT_APP_WARNING_COLOR,
                        process.env.REACT_APP_DANGER_COLOR,
                    ],
                    plotOptions: {
                        candlestick: {
                            colors: {
                                upward: process.env.REACT_APP_SUCCESS_COLOR,
                                downward: process.env.REACT_APP_DANGER_COLOR,
                            },
                        },
                        boxPlot: {
                            colors: {
                                upper: process.env.REACT_APP_SUCCESS_COLOR,
                                lower: process.env.REACT_APP_DANGER_COLOR,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    ...options,
                }}
                series={series}
                // @ts-ignore
                type={type}
                width={width}
                height={height}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "qconnect-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "2.0.17 ",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "2.4.9",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.8.1",
    "@hello-pangea/dnd": "^16.2.0",
    "@natscale/react-calendar": "0.0.0-beta.23",
    "@omtanke/react-use-event-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@reactour/tour": "^3.2.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.8.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "apexcharts": "^3.40.0",
    "axios": "0.27.2",
    "chart.js": "3.9.1",
    "chartjs-chart-treemap": "2.0.2",
    "chroma-js": "2.4.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "env-cmd": "10.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^9.1.7",
    "i18next": "^22.4.10",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.0.1",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^2.1.1",
    "jsx-to-string": "^1.4.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "pascalcase": "^2.0.0",
    "payment": "^2.4.6",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "qs": "6.11.0",
    "randomcolor": "0.6.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^1.6.8",
    "react-chartjs-2": "4.1.0",
    "react-credit-cards": "^0.8.3",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-datepicker": "4.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.2.0",
    "react-image-webp": "^0.8.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-jss": "^10.10.0",
    "react-modern-calendar-datepicker": "^3.1.6",
    "react-moment": "1.1.2",
    "react-notifications-component": "^4.0.1",
    "react-number-format": "^5.1.3",
    "react-popper": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "8.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-scrollspy": "^3.4.3",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0",
    "react-toast-notifications": "^2.5.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "2.4.1",
    "use-clipboard-copy": "^0.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^3.1.1",
    "yarn": "1.22.19",
    "@ionic/cli": "^7.1.1",
        "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
        "swiper": "^9.2.4"

  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start:prod": "env-cmd -f ./.env.prod npm run-script start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f ./.env.prod npm run-script build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "serve": "serve -s build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js --ext .ts --ext .jsx --ext .tsx ./src",
    "lint:scss": "stylelint **/*.scss",
    "lint:fix-scss": "stylelint --fix **/*.scss",
    "icon": "svgr SvgIcons -d src/components/icon/svg-icons --typescript",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "storybook-withoutCache": "start-storybook -p 6006 --no-manager-cache",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@modules": "build/modules",
    "@core": "build/core"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      ">0.2%"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "6.3.1",
    "@svgr/cli": "^6.5.1",
    "@types/pascalcase": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/payment": "^2.1.4",
    "@types/prismjs": "^1.26.0",
    "@types/react-big-calendar": "^1.6.0",
    "@types/react-credit-cards": "^0.8.1",
    "@types/react-date-range": "^1.4.4",
    "@types/react-input-mask": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.5",
    "@types/react-scrollspy": "^3.3.5",
    "@types/react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.6",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "@whitespace/storybook-addon-html": "^5.1.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.58.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "storybook-addon-jsx": "^7.3.15-canary.162.1301.0",
    "stylelint": "^15.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier-scss": "^0.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^30.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^7.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-twbs-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "stylelint-declaration-block-no-ignored-properties": "^2.7.0",
    "stylelint-declaration-strict-value": "^1.9.2",
    "stylelint-no-px": "^1.0.1",
    "stylelint-order": "^6.0.2",
    "stylelint-prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^4.4.0",
    "trim-newlines": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack": "5",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!pascalcase|prismjs|@omtanke/react-use-event-outside/.*)"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "glob-parent": ">=5.1.2",
    "json5": ">=2.2.2",
    "nth-check": ">=2.1.1",
    "trim": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "glob-parent": ">=5.1.2",
    "json5": ">=2.2.2",
    "nth-check": ">=2.1.1",
    "trim": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

And this is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
    "ts-node": {
        // Do not forget to `npm i -D tsconfig-paths`
        "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
    },
    // "extends":"@tsconfig/node12/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",        // path to output directory
        "sourceMap": true,          // allow sourcemap support
        "strictNullChecks": true,   // enable strict null checks as a best practice
        "module": "CommonJS",            // specify module code generation
        "jsx": "react-jsx",             // use typescript to transpile jsx to js
        "target": "ESNext",            // specify ECMAScript target version
        "allowJs": true,             // allow a partial TypeScript and JavaScript codebase
        "skipLibCheck": true,

        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "es7","DOM"],
        // "target": "es2017",
        // "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "rootDir": "src",
        // "outDir": "build",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strict": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,

        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@modules/*": ["src/modules/*"],
            "*": ["node_modules/*"]
        },
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "typeRoots" : ["node_modules/@types", "src/type"]
        // "preserveConstEnums": true


    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*",
        "./src/index.d.ts",
        "./src/declaration.d.ts"

    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "./node_modules",
        "./node_modules/*",
        // "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
      ]
}
```

I verified if the state and props are properly passed to the components by doing runtime debugging using browser's developer tools.

I verified if there are any version mismatch present and tried with various versions of react apex chart libraries.

I dont think I have any issue with respect to data (state and props) and version as well.

Comment: Go to node_modules, find package put a console.log in there…

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution from here

https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/1297

basically, the data series is async, and it is loaded before the data available. in order to solve the problem, just do something like this

```
salary[0] === undefined ? [] : salary
```